# How can I replace the quotes and the words inside them with brackets with notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm working on a .csv file and I want to replace

```
"something1","something2","something3"
```

to

```
[something1],[something2],[something3]
```

How can I do this in 1 go? I couldn't find the right expression.

Much appreciated.
Klive

Comment: That looks suspiciously like MSSQL column delimiting. Just throwing this out there, if you are converting a SQL script to MSSQL, that database engine accepts both square brackets and double quotes as database object name delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option, assuming your double quotes are always balanced:

```
Find: "([^"]+)"
Replace: [$1]
```

### Demo

We can match and capture all content inside double quotes, then replace it with that content inside square brackets.